# AT&T UVerse debugging after lightning strike

Tags: networking, wired-networking

My AT&T UVerse modem fails to connect after a recent lightning strike. I've done some basic debugging:

- If I connect the modem to the jack in the telephone network interface box outside my house, it works.
- Inside my house, near where the wire comes in, there is a "post block" where tip & ring are all connected to the wires for the two phone jacks in my house. If I disconnect my inside wiring from the "post block" and only have the tip & ring wires twisted together, the inside house jack where I normally connect the modem then works.

This leads me to believe the "post block" is the issue. It is a hollow bakelite block, about 2.25" x 0.75" x 0.75", potted with thermoplastic. I can't read the trademark, but the numbers on the side are:
26-85  365-L  TFS

What is this thing? Is it a surge protector? It has two screw posts and a mounting tab, which I assume is ground. As installed, it had three 0.02uf caps connected between the posts, and from each post to the mounting tab. I have tested all with an ohm meter, and all are open (or at least very high resistance). I have not tried the re-challenge of connecting all these things back as they were since I wanted to send this message out first.

Comment: What exactly is your question?  If your modem is not acquring a connection with your service provider, and you had lighting hit your house, sounds like your device is toast and should be replaced.

Comment: The OP notes that the modem works when certain sections of the internal wiring are disconnected/bypassed.  It appears that he's narrowed it down to an undefined connection device described as a post block. My guess (not an answer) is the caps may be a factor.

Comment: Your question title needs to be rephrased to reflect your actual question which is about identifying the post block.

Comment: Can you attach an image? It can be very difficult to identify equipment based on descriptions alone.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in the US or countries that wire similarly, it sounds like you're looking at the NID, or "Network Interface Device."  It sounds like a technical thing, but its actually legal.  Anything "inside" that point is your (or the property owners) responsibility to maintain.  Everything outside belongs to the provider and is off limits for you to touch -- although myself and many others in networking centers have regularly dinked past that limit when working with engineers, it is at your own risk, as you are technically responsible for anything you break.

I have not run into problems with the NID itself, so I don't know who is responsible for the actual box.  Wikipedia says the provider is responsible for the NID itself, which I assume at least covers the US.

Reference, plus some pictures and examples with a T1, fiber, etc: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_interface_device

Answer (score 0):

The "post block" is a gas-discharge surge arrestor. Though the part number is not exact, this one looks the same: tiitech.com/repository/datasheetlibrary/356.pdf